# Error with openpyxl.workbook.Workbook.save() method

Tags: excel, python-3.x, python-3.3, openpyxl

So if I have this code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.create_sheet(0)
    ws.title = 'Title'

    ws.cell('A3').value = 8

    wb.save('temp.xlsx')
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/openpyxl/workbook.py", line 233, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 159, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 142, in save
    self.write_data(archive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 83, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets(archive, shared_string_table, self.style_writer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 104, in _write_worksheets
    style_writer.get_style_by_hash()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/worksheet.py", line 96, in write_worksheet
    for range_string, rules in worksheet.conditional_formatting.cf_rules.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

I can't even get the simplest spreadsheet to work.  They all show this error.

openpyxl 1.8.0 / python 3.3.2

What am I doing wrong?

Update: The python script is for python 3, but if I run it with python 2.7.5 the script works.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: In Python 3 dicts only have an `.items()` method. It works in Python 2.7 because in that version dicts have both `.iteritems()` and `.items()` methods. In the latest source it seems that the issue has been fixed: https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/diff/openpyxl/worksheet.py?diff2=f3c22226246c&at=default

Answer (score 0):

This definitely cannot have been with openpyxl 1.8 which was only released in January 2014. The original bug was fixed in 1.7 which passed all tests with Python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.2 and 3.3